# Laptop [1000 - 1500e] for 3D modeling, animating and rendering on Blender

Tags: laptop

I want a laptop to work on 3D (Blender, mainly). My budget is between 1000 and 1500e. Any recommendation? Mi biggest problem with laptops have always been heat, so I'm looking for one that can render for 6-7 hours without turning off.

How good can be a Macbook Pro to work on 3D? Can I have any problem when exporting any blender file made in Windows into a Mac?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not experienced with Blender, is the operation which's time you want to minimize bound by the CPU or the GPU mainly and how much RAM do you need (depending on your answers, there are some tricks to get better performance).

Comment: Also: Is high disk performance important, that is during the operation do you need to quickly read / write _a lot_ (multiple GB) of data to the drive?

Comment: @SEJPM The operation I want to minimize is by GPU, and it should have at least 4gb of vram. About the RAM, I think 16 GB would be perfect.

Comment: High disk performance is not priority. But having a ssd disk to run my system is important to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any recommendation?

Essentially, anything that has a Nvidia Geforce GTX 1070 or GTX 1080 will work for you. However due to your budget, finding a 1070-based model is more likely. The other caveats that you have to look out for are the 16GB of RAM that you specified, the SSD and that the CPU (most likely an Intel model) has **HQ** or **HK** at the end of the name and *not* **U**, because the latter would indicate a dual-core CPU limited to 28W or 15W power-consumption as opposed to a quad-core at 45W. Any laptop that satisfies these above constraints should work.

Beyond that, note that you probably want to clean the fans every now and then (1x a month if you can) to make sure the air can flow and cool the system properly, so that you don't get reduced performance or sudden heat-caused shutdowns.

Because I have to, I'll make a generic recommendation fitting your budget:

The **Asus ROG GL502VS-FY042T**:

- It features an Nvidia GTX 1070 GPU (-> 8GB of VRAM) meaning it's about the best you can get from a 1500€ laptop
- It features a standard quad-core 45W Skylake laptop CPU: the i7-6700HQ
- It features 16GB of RAM
- It features a 512GB SSD paired with a 1TB HDD
- It's priced at 1499€ (at least in Germany, should be similar in other european countries)